# getting notifications about updates only in the "core" page

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, admin, updates, core

I run a few WP sites and keep track of updates on a daily basis.
Normally, I go into the Plugins page and check if there are updates to the installed plugins accordingly.
Lately, I've found out that even though this page doesn't show new updates, when I go into the "/wp-admin/update-core.php" page, suddenly there are updates and from now one, the Plugins page will show these updates too. It looks like the "core" page triggers a true check for updates and only then, the admin recognizes these updates and shows them normally, as described here.

Why is that?? Am I missing something here? What can I check and how can I get the admin behavior back to its "normal" state?

I should mention that I'm not sure when this started to happen like that, as I doscovered that by mistake when working on something else...

Answer (score 1):

WordPress uses CRON job to check for updates 2 times a day. But, it will also check for updates anytime you visit Updates page.

When the update check is finished, results are cached and used until the next manual or scheduled check. Visiting Plugins page will show updates from these cached results only, it will not trigger update check.

Comment: a little addition : the plugins page doesn't trigger update check but the update page does.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how it should be, as I already said in the answer.

Comment: Ok, but I still don't understand why the automatic check, like you describe it here, seems to be "out of sync" with a real updates check. If the "Updates" page triggers a real check and then points out the current available updates, why didn't the automatic check do that the same way??

Comment: Because scheduled checks runs every 12 hours, and its results are delayed by that. Also, it is possible that these 12 hour scheduled checks don't work for you due to wp cron related issues.